# What's the point of review queue if I can't flag anything?

Tags: support, bug, review, flags, declined-flags

I had 2 flag declined (for marking these two posts low quality: [1](https://superuser.com/a/974565/87805) and [2](https://superuser.com/a/973095/87805) - which I still believe they are) and having that, I've the error message, when I want to flag another question as part of the review queue (First Posts):

> Too many of your recent flags have been declined - please review them instead of flagging this post!

I understand I should wait a week, so the error disappear it-self, but how do I now flag questions during review queue?

[image]

Currently every option is greyed out and if I don't have possibility to flag the questions, there is no point of doing review queues. Is that the expected behaviour? I could down-vote (which I believe it should work in most of the cases), but I prefer to use flag functionality.

Is there any other workaround?

To compare other queues, seems Low Quality Posts queue works fine (Recommend Deletion), despite my flag limitation therefore I believe this should work in similar way for First Posts.

[image]

So I'm finding this a bit inconsistent.

Is it because I don't have enough reputation to close the question (3k at SU)? Then I wouldn't have this issue? Is there anything here to improve how the things works?

My logical explanation is, if I am able to Recommend a Deletion, I should clearly be able to mark the post as a low quality also.

Comment: Are you asking for a work around for the flag block...? If you get the flag block it's a "Bad Thing" - you do need to wait and evaluate.

Comment: @Tim I could wait, not a problem. But Yes, some work around this area should be considered as it looks like inconsistent behaviour for me. I can vote to delete, but I can't flag that the answer is a 'comment' or 'thank you' (because of only 2 declined flags). Secondly how do I reject post in First Posts, when I can't (the only way is to down-vote, but it won't help towards closure).